# document.getelementbyid not recognizing razor element

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my index.cshtml file I have a razor element (@Html.EditorFor) that's a text box. Javascript isn't recognizing the element. If I change the element type to a non-razor syntax then javascript can see it. Am I missing some syntax here.

index.cshtml

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>my application</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        //javascript can't see mainpagequery
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchQuery, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "mainpagequery" }})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchQuery, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        //javascript can see mainpagequery in the non razor element here
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="mainpagequery">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
}
```

Here is my javascript. If I use razor then 'mainpagequery' is underlines because it can't see it, if I use html then it's fine. I know I'm hitting my javascript because I see the alert message pop up.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log("ready!");
alert("mainpage autocomplete function entered");

var input = document.getElementById('mainpagequery');
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: "us" }
};
var mainpagequery = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
});
```

Comment: MVC-4 does not support adding html attributes in `EditorFor()` so the `id` attribute would not be added and the ID would be the default - i.e. `id="SearchQuery"` (are you using MVC-4 or MVC-5.1+ or a custom `EditorTemplate`?)

Comment: Then you should remove the MVC-4 tag and add the correct tag.

Comment: where can I get info on the difference in tags between mvc4 and 5? What I did was I upgraded to 5 half way through implementation. So I know I have incorrect tags all over the place. :(

Comment: [getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)  generally works better for me with razor than hunting by ID.

Answer (score 1):

In case of  `@Html.EditorFor` your id get overriden to model's property name.

If you find element using f12 you will find it as follows. (Notice id "**SearchQuery124**" I just renamed it to something)

[image]

So in your case in make change like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    alert("mainpage autocomplete function entered");

    var input = document.getElementById('SearchQuery').value;
    console.log(input);
    var options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: { country: "us" }
    };
    var mainpagequery = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Instead of  `@Html.EditorFor` use

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchQuery, new { @class = "form-control" , id = "mainpagequery"})
```